# Using regex to make edits on multiple lines

Tags: regex

I have downloaded an sql file and would like to mass replace some names of pages I have created.

This is an example of one page:
`{\"ref\":\"Session_1___Pg1___V2\",\"pageTitle\":null,\"description\":null,\"revealDate\":0,\"gQRef\":null,\"lQRef\":null,\"gQScore\":null,\"lQScore\":null,\"newsfeedDates\":null,\"subtitle\":null,\"pageLinkTitle\":null,\"linkTitle\":null,\"pageBack\":null,\"pagePrint\":false,\"visitedFlag\":null,\"widthPercentage\":0,\"maxWidth\":0,\"thumbnail\":null,\"edit\":null,\"copy\":null,\"delete\":null,\"preview\":null}]}`

How do I search and highlight all the references of each page, just like `Session_1___Pg1___V2` from above, without selecting anything else. I have hundreds of pages that I need to change the references of and I think regex would be the best way to do it with.

I used `(\"((.*?))\")` but it would select everything that is inbetween quotes. How do I just select the `ref` of the pages?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a lookbehind:

```
(?<=\\"ref\\":\\)"([^"]+)"
```

- `(?<=\\"ref\\":\\)` Lookbehind for `\"ref\":\` substring.
- `"([^"]+)"` Matches `"`, opens capture group, capturing anything other than a `"`. Then closes capturing group and matches `"`.

The result is group:

```
Group 1.    11-32   `Session_1___Pg1___V2\`
```

Regex demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/6LqnO6/1).